# Establishing trusted communication between SAP and C# using X509 certificates and .NET Connector

Tags: .net, x509, sap-erp, trusted

I need to allow a C# application running on one machine access to a SAP ERP system using the .NET Connector library. The systems need to be set up with X.509 certificates in order to be trusted systems.

Can anybody inform how to set the certificates up on both machines, in order to establish a trusted system?

I need to perform a RFC into the SAP ERP system from the C# application; I assume that both systems need to be trusted in this scenario.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: What is the purpose of establishing trust between the c# application host? Do you need to enable encryption or do you want to use X509 for authentication to remove the use of a password for that connection or do you want to use SSO?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure about the need for trust, because I inherited the support role of this project; the original architect and others familiar with the reasoning have long since left the company, and reasons for such decisions do not seem to be documented.

I've learnt a lot more about certification on C# and .NET thanks to Andras Nemes' excellent Blog at https://dotnetcodr.com/security-and-cryptography/

What I have discovered is that the solution is using server-side certification, and the solution is currently using SAP SSO.

Comment: I see. I will write an answer to this when I get time that I hope will solve your problem.

Comment: I would certainly appreciate that, thanks!